# Swiper JS - Centering image horizontal and vertically

Tags: swiper.js

I'm trying to center an image inside the slide (swiper) both horizontal and vertically. Kind of the same behavior when we put `background-size: cover` when it's a div's background image.

By default it shows the image from the top left corner, so I'm trying to change that behavior. What I've tried is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="banner.jpg">  
            <div class="caption-align">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                    <p>Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.swiper-container {     
    height: 650px;
}

.caption-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Vertically it works fine. Horizontally it cuts the image somehow when pulling it to the left:

[image]

Without the X translate:

[image]

Any tips?